# Crosstalk vs interference

Tags: telephone

I don't even clear about the differences between crosstalk and interference. Could you explain me please?

I just know that cross talk is the leakage power from other sources, whereas interference is the aliasing signal.

Could you tell me any other differences?

Comment: It may need some context to differentiate them. May at different field, they have different meaning. Generally, crosstalk may be a kind of interference.

Answer (score 4):

Crosstalk is a type of interference.  Interference can come from just about anywhere - e.g. RF interference from all sorts of things emitting radio waves (including, but not limited to, radio transmitters).  Interference can also come from coupling from other devices.  In the case of a phone system, this could be hearing humming from a power line or music from the local AM radio station on the phone line.  Generally crosstalk refers to interference from an 'adjacent' signal - be it in a wire, radio channel, etc - leaking into the 'victim' signal.  In the case of a phone system, this could be in the form of being able to hear your neighbor's phone calls on your line because the two lines are routed next to each other on the telephone pole.

Comment: Crosstalk can also be directly conducted into the victim, e.g. through improper earthing arrangements or poor power supplies.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia gives a reasonable summary of the types of interference, of which crosstalk is one:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_%28communication%29

Comment: Link-only answers are likely to become unhelpful over time. Can you summarize what's in the linked article?